# What are node libraries to send mail that support TLS/STARTTLS negotiation?

Tags: email, node.js

What are libraries for node version 0.4.1 that send mail and support TLS/STARTTLS negotiation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs)? According to the examples they support connecting to gmail (uses ssl).

Hope it helps!

Comment: For anything else, I strongly recommend that you check the "semi official" list of node.js modules: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer so you might want to give that a shot.